# Find duplicated nested directories

Tags: bash, duplicates, subdirectory

I have a large directory tree with this nested directories duplicates (but not all):

- data/home/home/
- data/banners/banners/
- resources/users/documents/documents/

How can I merge only duplicated directories with this actions:

- copy (without replace) **data/home/home/** contents to **data/home/**
- delete **data/home/home**

My current code:

```sh
#/bin/bash

for folder in $(find httpdocs -type d); do
    n=$(echo $folder | tr "/" "\n" | wc -l)
    nuniq=$(echo $folder | tr "/" "\n" | sort | uniq | wc -l)

    [ $n -eq $nuniq ] || echo "Duplicated folder $folder"
done
```

But have a problem, because **data/home/es/home** is a valid folder, but detected as duplicated.

Thanks.

Comment: You might need to show your attempts in order to get replies from other users.

Comment: @Fazlin, I don't know how I can try to do it. I know major linux commands and I know how I can do it with a double for and counters in bash, but I need some more optimizated. I will post an example ASAP. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use uniq command like this:

```bash
#/bin/bash

for folder in $(find httpdocs -type d); do
    nuniq=$(echo $folder | tr "/" "\n"  | uniq -d | wc -l)
     if [ "$nuniq" -gt "0" ]
      then
        echo "Duplicated folder $folder"
      fi
done
```

> man uniq;
>
> ```
>   -d, --repeated
>           only print duplicate lines
> ```

You can try the following script to copy and delete folders. I did not test this, so backup your `httpdocs` folder before running this.

```bash
#/bin/bash

for folder in $(find httpdocs -type d); do
    nuniq=$(echo $folder | tr "/" "\n"  | uniq -d | wc -l)
     if [ "$nuniq" -gt "0" ]
      then
        dest=$(echo $folder | tr '/' '\n' | awk '!a[$0]++' | tr '\n' '/')
        mv -i $folder/*  $dest
        rmdir $folder 
      fi
done
```

For example:

```
user@host $ echo "data/home/es/home" | tr "/" "\n"  
data
home
es
home

user@host $ echo "data/home/es/home" | tr "/" "\n"  | uniq -d | wc -l 
0

user@host $ echo "data/home/home" | tr "/" "\n"  
data
home
home

user@host $ echo "data/home/home" | tr "/" "\n" | uniq -d 
home

user@host $ echo "data/home/home" | tr "/" "\n" | uniq -d | wc -l
1
```